# How to assign inputs to program with arbitrary order?

Tags: java

I have four inputs into my code and what I want to be able to do is input them in the console in any order I choose.

So I could input:

t = 20, d = 100, T = 500, D = 100

or

d = 100, t = 20, D = 100, T = 500

So, regardless of order as long as I type "t = something" , "d = something" , T = "something" and D = "something" it will assign the correct integer value into the variables.

This is what I have so far:

`int t = keyboard.nextInt(); int d = keyboard.nextInt(); int D = keyboard.nextInt(); int  T = keyboard.nextInt();`

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You'd probably use a `Map<String, Integer>` instead of explicit variables

Comment: First off I would remove the spacing between the = sign, then read the entire line as a string and parse that

Comment: Thank you, this is my first class in java (python backround) and our professor has not gone over anything that has to do with what you mentioned. Would there possibly be a more simplistic solution that novices to java would know about?

Comment: @John The String class is one you'll be using quite often, so I expect you'll find great benefit in learning some of its methods early on

Answer (score 1):

I'd first follow OldProgrammer's suggestion and read the line as a single String. You could parse the string using the `split()` and `substring()`  methods:

```
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
               // Per your example, would be something like "t=20,d=100,T=500,D=100"
int t = 0, d = 0, T = 0, D = 0;

String[] inputArray = input.split(","); // Splits the input string at each comma & returns an array

for(String s : inputArray) {
    if(s.startsWith("t"))
            t = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2));
    else if(s.startsWith("d"))
            d = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2));
    else if(s.startsWith("T"))
            T = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2));
    else if(s.startsWith("D"))
            D = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are entering them 1 by 1, use this**

Use a 'switch'. Just replace the commented lines with assignment to the appropriate variable.

```
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        switch (input.split(" = ")[0]) {
            case "D":
                // assign value to capital D
                break;
            case "T":
                // code 
                break;
            case "d":
                // code block
                break;
            case "t":
                // code block
                break;
            default:
               // error message

        }
```

**If you are entering the entire `d = 100, t = 20, D = 100, T = 500` as one line, use this:**

```
String line = "d = 100, t = 20, D = 100, T = 500"; // substitute nextLine() here
    String[] split_line = line.split(", ");
    for (String input : split_line){
        switch (input.split(" = ")[0]) {
            case "D":
                System.out.println(input.split(" = ")[1]);
                break;
            case "T":
                // code
                break;
            case "d":
                // code block
                break;
            case "t":
                // code block
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Needs 'default' to handle invalid input.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas added.

Comment: `input.split` the sample input line would give you `[ "t", "20, d", "100, T" (etc) ]` - you'd have to split on comma first, and _then_ split on equals.

Comment: @StephenP is it supposed to accept the entire line or just one of them?

Comment: OP is not explicit, but the sample in the question is `t = 20, d = 100, T = 500, D = 100` which I take to be one input line consisting of a comma-separated list of assignments. I personally would code it to allow optional whitespace around the comma and around the equal sign, as Andrews answer does in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be

```
public final class Example {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final int variablesExpected = 3;
        final Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<>();
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // read until there are 3 varibles
        while(variables.size() != variablesExpected) {
            // read a line from the user
            final String line = keyboard.nextLine();
            // split it into 2 Strings (hopefully): varible name and varible value
            final String[] expression = line.split("\\s*=\\s*");

            if (expression.length == 2) {
                // expression[0] is the variable name
                // Integer.valueOf(expression[1]) is its integer value
                variables.put(expression[0], Integer.valueOf(expression[1]));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(variables);
    }
}
```

An input example would be

```
t = 4
T=3
R   = 15

{R=15, t=4, T=3}
```

It's more flexible and doesn't force the user to input the exact variable names you defined. If it's a requirement, define a `Set<String>`, and, for each input, check if the first part of expression presents in that `Set`.

```
public final class Example {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
        final Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<>();
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        final Set<String> expectedVariableNames = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("t", "T", "d", "D"));

        while(variables.size() != expectedVariableNames.size()) {
            final String line = keyboard.nextLine();
            final String[] expression = line.split("\\s*=\\s*");

            if (expression.length == 2 && expectedVariableNames.contains(expression[0])) {
                variables.put(expression[0], Integer.valueOf(expression[1]));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(variables);
    }
}
```

You will be inputting values until there are `expectedVariableNames.size()` variables.

```
t = 3
d = 3
D       // invalid
d = 45  // overrides d = 3
D = 12 
l = 34  // invalid
T = 12

{t=3, d=45, D=12, T=12}
```